# Sonata Page Bundle : BlockCreate not loading Layout

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm installing Sonata Page Bundle, everything is ok, except the fact that when i try to create a block, the step where i choose the Block type, i get a page without layout (please see the attached screenshot)

[image: Admin Interface : Create Block]

here is my sonata_page.yml config file:

```
sonata_page:
    slugify_service:   sonata.core.slugify.cocur # old BC value is sonata.core.slugify.native
    multisite:        host
    default_template: default # template key from templates section, used as default for
    templates:
        default:
            path: '::base.html.twig'
            name: 'default'
            containers:
                header:
                    name: Header
                content_top:
                    name: Top content
                content:
                    name: Main content
                content_bottom:
                    name: Bottom content
                footer:
                    name: Footer
            matrix:
                layout: |
                    HHHHHHHH
                    TTTTBBBB
                    TTTTBBBB
                    TTTTBBBB
                    TTTTBBBB
                    CCCCCCCC
                    CCCCCCCC
                    FFFFFFFF

                mapping:
                    H: header
                    T: content_top
                    C: content
                    B: content_bottom
                    F: footer

    # Generates a snapshot when a page is saved (from the admin)
    direct_publication: false # or %kernel.debug% if you want to publish in dev mode (but not in prod)

    multisite: host
    use_streamed_response: true # set the value to false in debug mode or if the reverse proxy does not handle streamed response
    ignore_route_patterns:
        - ^(.*)admin(.*)   # ignore admin route, ie route containing 'admin'
        - ^_(.*)          # ignore symfony routes

    ignore_routes:
        - sonata_page_cache_esi
        - sonata_page_cache_ssi
        - sonata_page_js_sync_cache
        - sonata_page_js_async_cache
        - sonata_cache_esi
        - sonata_cache_ssi
        - sonata_cache_js_async
        - sonata_cache_js_sync
        - sonata_cache_apc

    ignore_uri_patterns:
        - ^/admin\/   # ignore admin route, ie route containing 'admin'

    page_defaults:
        homepage: {decorate: false} # disable decoration for homepage, key - is a page route


    # manage the http errors
    catch_exceptions:
        not_found: [404]    # render 404 page with "not_found" key (name generated: _page_internal_error_{key})
        fatal:     [500]    # so you can use the same page for different http errors or specify specific page for each error


cmf_routing:
    chain:
        routers_by_id:
            # enable the DynamicRouter with high priority to allow overwriting configured routes with content
            # cmf_routing.dynamic_router: 200
            # enable the symfony default router with a lower priority
            sonata.page.router: 150
            router.default: 100
```

have i missed something somewhere ?

thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to file app\config\config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
  assets:
      javascripts:
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery-form/jquery.form.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.confirmExit.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/iCheck/icheck.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/waypoints/lib/shortcuts/sticky.min.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/Admin.js
          - bundles/sonataadmin/treeview.js
          - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.js

      stylesheets:
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/skin-black.min.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/iCheck/skins/square/blue.css
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.css
          - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.min.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/css/styles.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/css/layout.css
          - bundles/sonataadmin/css/tree.css
          - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.css
```